# How to write an API to get sales report of the last 1 year?

Tags: magento2, api, sales-order, reports

I'm writing an module that provide a new API endpoint for Magento 2.
Can anyone guide on how to write an API endpoint that I can fetch the sales report of last 1 year ?

Comment: Elaborate your question with tested code

Comment: If you want to use core APIs then Magento  already provide list of APIs for sales http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/rest/list.html

Comment: Check Magento documentation in order to create a custom API. Then check a sales report repository in order to fetch data.